# Close MS Access from a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to close an MS Acess database from a DOS batch file. I found on StackOverflow a command that looks similar to :-

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2" %i IN (`tasklist ^| findstr /r /b "MSACCESS.EXE"`) DO taskkill /pid %i
```

When I run this at the command line it works fine. When I place the exact same line in a batch file I get the error :-

```
i was unexpected at this time.
```

Comment: taskkill /im MSACCESS.EXE would be a lot eaiser - thank you.

Comment: Do you have your answer now? If you want to post it, you could mark it as the answer, and we could +1 it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
taskkill /im MSACCESS.EXE /t /f
```

Without the /t /f the process would remain open if a critical message box was being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Noting this for future readers. I know this is an old post.
The exact same line will not work.

You would need to have %%i in a batch file in all instances you have a %i.

So more like this:

`FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2" %%i IN (tasklist ^| findstr /r /b "MSACCESS.EXE") DO taskkill /pid %%i`